# Kind mismatch with GHC.Generics

Tags: haskell, generics

I'm trying to write a generic vector space implementation in Haskell. My implementation is as follows:

```
import qualified GHC.Generics as G
import GHC.Generics hiding (V1)

class GVecSpace v where
  addVs :: v -> v -> v
  scaleV :: Double -> v -> v

instance GVecSpace (G.V1 a) where
  addVs _ _ = undefined
  scaleV _ _ = undefined

instance GVecSpace (G.U1 a) where
  addVs _ x = x -- no value
  scaleV _ x = x -- no value

instance (GVecSpace (f a), GVecSpace (g a)) => GVecSpace ((f :+: g) a) where
  addVs (L1 x) (L1 y) = L1 $ addVs x y
  addVs (R1 x) (R1 y) = R1 $ addVs x y
  scaleV d (L1 x) = L1 $ scaleV d x
  scaleV d (R1 x) = R1 $ scaleV d x

instance (GVecSpace (f a), GVecSpace (g a)) => GVecSpace ((f :*: g) a) where
  addVs (x1 :*: x2) (y1 :*: y2) =
    addVs x1 y1 :*: addVs x2 y2
  scaleV d (x1 :*: x2) =
    scaleV d x1 :*: scaleV d x2

instance (GVecSpace c) => GVecSpace (K1 i c p) where
  addVs (K1 x) (K1 y) = K1 $ addVs x y
  scaleV d (K1 x) = K1 $ scaleV d x

instance (GVecSpace (f p)) => GVecSpace (M1 i c f p) where
  addVs (M1 x) (M1 y) = M1 $ addVs x y
  scaleV d (M1 x) = M1 $ scaleV d x

instance (Generic a, GVecSpace (Rep a)) => GVecSpace a where
  addVs x y =
    G.to $ addVs (G.from x) (G.from y)
  scaleV d x =
    G.to $ scaleV d (G.from x)
```

But GHC complains because `Rep a` has the wrong kind:

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘Rep a’
The first argument of ‘GVecSpace’ should have kind ‘*’,
  but ‘Rep a’ has kind ‘* -> *’
In the instance declaration for ‘GVecSpace a’
```

What should I change to make this work? One option is to make `GVecSpace` only work for kinds of `* -> *`, but that seems awkward. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: You may be interested in the [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) package which defines fine-grained classes for vector spaces: an [`AdditiveGroup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.9/docs/Data-AdditiveGroup.html#t:AdditiveGroup), a [`VectorSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.9/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#t:VectorSpace) and an inner product space, [`InnerProduct`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.9/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#t:InnerSpace).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a library that uses [`GHC.Generics`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/GHC-Generics.html) we first need a few pre-requisites.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import GHC.Generics as G
```

All of the representations for generics carry around an extra type parameter called "the parameter" `p`. You can see this in the kind of the type `Rep a` in the `Generic a` class, `type Rep a :: * -> *`. The representation for a data type isn't just another data type, it's a type with the kind `* -> *`, the same kind as `Functor`s and `Monad`s. It take another type as a parameter. Most of the time defining instances for a class based on the generic representations, we will just ignore the parameter.

Due to the extra parameter, it's useful to define a non-generic class. We'll be adding more to this later.

```
class VecSpace v where
    addVs :: v -> v -> v
    scaleV :: Double -> v -> v

    ...
```

The generic version of the class, `GVecSpace`, has an extra parameter `a` on the types of all the values. Everywhere we used `v` before, we will use `f a`. We will make new names for `GVecSpace` by prepending `g` to the names from `VecSpace`.

```
class GVecSpace f where
    gaddVs :: f a -> f a -> f a
    gscaleV :: Double -> f a -> f a
```

The `GVecSpace` class is a little awkward and only works for the kind `* -> *`, but it is only used for making the default implementations for `VecSpace`. You will use `VecSpace` everywhere else.

Unit types with only a single constructor are vector spaces. Note that `G.U1` is not applied to a parameter.

```
instance GVecSpace G.U1 where
  gaddVs _ x = x -- no value
  gscaleV _ x = x -- no value
```

The product of two vector spaces is a vector space. Note that `f` and `g` and `f :*: g` aren't applied to a parameter type.

```
instance (GVecSpace f, GVecSpace g) => GVecSpace (f :*: g) where
  gaddVs (x1 :*: x2) (y1 :*: y2) =
    gaddVs x1 y1 :*: gaddVs x2 y2
  gscaleV d (x1 :*: x2) =
    gscaleV d x1 :*: gscaleV d x2
```

For `K1` we drop the final parameter `p` from the type, and define it in terms of the non-generic `VecSpace`. The `c` parameter only has kind `*`, an ordinary type, so it can't be an instance of `GVecSpace`.

```
instance (VecSpace c) => GVecSpace (K1 i c) where
  gaddVs (K1 x) (K1 y) = K1 $ addVs x y
  gscaleV d (K1 x) = K1 $ scaleV d x
```

For `M1` metadata nodes, we drop the final paramter `p` from the type.

```
instance (GVecSpace f) => GVecSpace (M1 i c f) where
  gaddVs (M1 x) (M1 y) = M1 $ gaddVs x y
  gscaleV d (M1 x) = M1 $ gscaleV d x
```

Now we can return to the `VecSpace` class and fill in the defaults for how something is a `VecSpace` when its representation has a `GVecSpace` instance. We convert the arguments into the representation `from` the type `v`, perform the generic version of the operation on the representation, and then convert back `to` the type `v` when we're done.

```
class VecSpace v where
    addVs :: v -> v -> v
    scaleV :: Double -> v -> v

    default addVs :: (Generic v, GVecSpace (Rep v)) => v -> v -> v
    addVs x y = to (gaddVs (from x) (from y))

    default scaleV :: (Generic v, GVecSpace (Rep v)) => Double -> v -> v
    scaleV s = to . gscaleV s . from
```

#### Use

Assuming you have already observed that `Double`s form a vector space

```
instance VecSpace Double where
    addVs = (+)
    scaleV = (*)
```

we can derive a working `VecSpace` instance for tuples in terms of the `default`s in `VecSpace`.

```
instance (VecSpace a, VecSpace b) => VecSpace (a, b)
```